# Understanding mmap

Tags: memory, operating-system

I have been looking to get difference between malloc and mmap system call. What is the exact difference between these two? Which is recommended?

Answer (score 6):

mmap() is a system-level address to map data from a file on disk. With mmap() you can refer to any file on disk as if it is a simple byte[] array. It may be used in any of following applications.

- Whenever you request a data from a file on disk, it is loaded in RAM.
  If you have two separate programs requiring data from the same file,
  you can use mmap() to directly access that file from disk, thereby
  reducing otherwise redundant RAM usage.
- When you are dealing with data so large that it can't be fit in
  main memory (RAM), you might use mmap() to access portion of the data
  of the file which is physically stored on your disk, thereby, again
  reducing RAM usage and handling larger than RAM data effectively.

Note that in a 64-bit system mmap() can address any location on disk but not in a 32-bit system! Because in a 32-bit system the maximum addressable space is limited to 2^32 - 1 (4GB) but on a 64-bit system petabytes of locations can be addressed.

malloc() gives you a pointer to some space from heap (in RAM) to store a temporary object.

The only similarity between mmap() and malloc() is that they both return pointers. But mmap() points to memory on disk and malloc() points to memory on heap.

Answer (score 2):

`mmap()` doesn't actually load the file into memory (doesn't use any memory, but it takes up address space) but `malloc()` allocate memory form heap.

My recommendation is use `malloc()` for tiny objects and `mmap()` for large ones.

Comment: This information is not accurate.  mmap does load the file into memory - it maps kernel pages into user space.  There are lots of answers on stack overflow that detail how this works.  Alternatively read "Advanced Unix Programming" by Stevens.

Answer (score 1):

They are very different:

1. `malloc()` allocates memory from the heap;
2. `mmap()` is an API for [memory-mapped files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file).

In most circumstances they are not substitutions for one another, so the question about which is better doesn't really make a lot of sense.